# Validate part or the complete string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a match of a string when it start with a specific part of the word. It is difficult to explain so I'll give an example; I'm working on a script that checks what kind of network interface on a Cisco device the user needs. It can be either Ethernet, FastEthernet, GigabitEthernet or TenGigabitEthernet. The thing is; the user can specify these names with abbreviations. The string 'Fa' could be used for FastEthernet, for example, but also 'Fas', 'Fast', 'FastE', etc.

So what I need is a regex that gives me a positive match for FastEthernet when the user enters 'Fas' or Fast.

I tried the following regex;

^(Fa|Fas|Fast|FastE|FastEt|FastEth|FastEthe|FastEther|FastEthern|FastEtherne|FastEthernet)

Which works but is very ugly and not really portable.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

def get_interface(name):
    """ Return the full name of the interface """

    if re.match('^(Gi|Gig|Giga|Gigab|Gigabi|Gigabit|GigabitE|GigabitEt|GigabitEth|GigabitEthe|GigagibitEther|GigabitEthern|GigabitEtherne|GigabitEthernet)', name):
        return 'GigabitEthernet'
    elif re.match('^(Fa|Fas|Fast|FastE|FastEt|FastEth|FastEthe|FastEther|FastEthern|FastEtherne|FastEthernet)', name):
        return 'FastEthernet'
    elif re.match('^(Et|Eth|Ethe|Ether|Ethern|Etherne|Ethernet)', name):
        return 'Ethernet'


print(get_interface('Gi'))
```

No error messages.

Comment: `^Et(h(e(r(n(et?)?)?)?)?)?` Better looking regex in case anyone wonders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not actually require regexes, and is simpler without them.

The solution below scales well when adding new ethernet variants, and checks for ambiguous and unknown names.

```
variants = ["Ethernet", "FastEthernet", "GigabitEthernet", "TenGigabitEthernet"]

def get_interface(name):
    result = None
    for v in variants:
        if v.startswith(name):
            if result:
                raise KeyError("Ambiguous name")
            result = v
    if not result:
        raise KeyError("Unknown name")
    return result
```

Comment: So simple, haven't even thought about that. I was thinking to complex.

Thanks for the reply, really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
import re

name = 'Gig'

def get_interface(name):
    options = ['GigabitEthernet', 'FastEthernet', 'Ethernet']
    for option in options:
        if any(re.match(line, name) for line in [option[0:i+1] for i in range(len(option))]):
            return option
```

Output:

```
GigabitEthernet
```